# Simulate Keyboard Event, without using the keyboard

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, autohotkey

Short: Is it possible to write a program that presses a key as if it was input from the keyboard?       If yes: how?

Long: I want to make bots for games, which is not permitted.
I know how to write programs to type keystrokes but the problem is that there seems to be a difference between keystrokes entered via software and actual keystrokes from the keybord.
Obviously games block those kind of "automatic" inputs and accept only real ones.
Is it possible to bypass them? if yes how?

I tried python win32api, AutoHotKey(Ahk) send and controlsend. Everything worked outside the game, nothing on it.

Comment: I think this is what `pyautogui` is for.

Comment: However, it's generally possible for programs to ignore synthetic events. Games are likely to do this to prevent you from using a robot to play it.

Comment: So no, I don't think you can bypass these checks, they're a security feature.

Comment: but i've just found a program that does it (Auto Macro Recorder) and it works. So it's possible but how

Comment: Is the program installed with Admin privileges?

Comment: yes, but it only works for 1 minute if i don't pay

Comment: That's the explanation -- administrator applictions can bypass. So maybe if you run the game and the bot from and Administrator account.

Comment: When using AutoHotkey with games, occasionally you'll have to fiddle around with [SendMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SendMode.htm) and [SetKeyDelay](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SetKeyDelay.htm) in order to get the game to recognize the key press. Also, as was mentioned, if the game is running as administrator, the interacting program (i.e., script) also needs to be running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I think most games check how long the key is pressed, So this: `[key down] -> ~0ms -> [key up]` means that the game thinks you're automating the keyboard (or it doesn't recognize the keypress).
Add this function to your script:

```py
import pyautogui
import time
import random

def delayed_key(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown(key)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05, 0.1)) # adjust these values to your liking
    pyautogui.keyUp(key)
```

It randomizes the time a key is held down to simulate human input. Hope it helps.

-Leo